# PDOStatement's bindValue only working with value of "0"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get data from a MySQL database using PDO. For example, I would run `blixUserGetInfo("2767207")` if the user's id was *2767207*.

But, whenever I run it with a User ID other than *0*, `blixUserGetInfo("0")`, `null` is returned, and no errors are thrown, even though the supplied ID **does** exist in the database.

```
function blixUserGetInfo($userid){
    $connection = //database connection

    // replacing this with 
    // "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $userid"
    // works for some reason
    $statement = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?";
    $prepared = $connection->prepare($statement);

    $prepared->bindValue(1, $userid); //returns TRUE
    $prepared->execute(); //also returns TRUE

    $code = $prepared->errorCode(); //returns '00000' (no error)
    return $prepared->fetch(); //returns null
}
```

But, If I change `$statement` from

> "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?"

to

> "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $userid"

and remove the `bindValue` statement, it works as expected.

I've also tried changing the `bindValue` statement to `bindValue(1, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT)`, but still have no luck. Both of the times the statement [returns `true`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindvalue-returnvalues).

Why doesn't the first example work [like it should](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)? Is it a bug, am I doing something wrong, or is it expected behavior?

Comment: Why are you setting the `$connection` to `null`?

Comment: @Ja͢ck It closes the connection

Comment: @Ja͢ck Thanks for pointing that out about closing connections. I would think that it just prevents `execute()` from working... And anyways, I do the same thing in other places and it works fine.

Comment: Coming to think of it, `->fetch()` should return `false` instead of `null` if there are no records, so perhaps something else is afoot here.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I get the same result without it,I'll remove it from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really dislike this `bindValue` and `bindParam` complexity unless it's absolutely necessary. You can simplify your code using parameters for `execute`

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?";
$prepared = $connection->prepare($statement);
$prepared->execute(array($userid));
```

While i know this does not answer why bindValue is not working, it takes away having to worry about pass by reference and pass by value stuff which could be a factor in this question.

If this `execute` does not return an error and your table does have data for that condition than its almost surely going to return it.

Although i didn't confirm it but your act of setting the connection to null before you fetch might be the actual reason you fail to see any data. Why would you set the connection to `NULL` and try to fetch afterwards ?

Comment: @Jojodmo would you like to mention what the actual solution turned out to be? That will help future readers more than the green tick

Comment: I'm still trying to find out what happened... I tried again with the old method that I had (and also tried re-uploading the file), and got the same result. So, I then tried your suggestion. When your code worked, I tried moving back to the old code, and I no longer got the error. I think the php file may have been corrupted, I'm not entirely sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just not use the `bindValue()` function anymore.
The `bindParam()` function works better in this case. Use the value placeholder instead of `?`'s (`:[placeholder name]`)

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id";
$prepared = $connection->prepare($statement);
$prepared -> bindParam(":id", $value)
$prepared -> execute();
```

Comment: "The bindParam() function works better in this case" -- what's the difference (in this case)?

Comment: Oh, I just highlighted things in your paragraph to highlight your functions and such.

Comment: It just helps separate things like your `bindValue()` and `?` to indicate you are referring to code.

Comment: So it's still not obvious what is the significant difference between your code that would make it work? You changed the placeholder to a named one and  used `bindParam`. Okay. The problem is that if your code works, the OPs code would work as well.